# Making a wrapper div overlap two wider divs

Tags: css, html

I am trying to build a layout where I have two divs in the background that span 100% of the page and then a full height wrapper div of a smaller size for content that sits centered on the page. The issue I am having is while I can get the wrapper to sit correctly on top of the top div; I cannot get it to behave correctly on the bottom div. Here is an example:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.index-banner {
  background: #265f7a;
  height: 60%;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  background: #444;
  height: 200%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: -60%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
}

.footer-bg {
  background: #888;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  top: -85%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="index-banner"></div>
  <div class="wrapper"></div>
  <div class="footer-bg"></div>
</body>
```

Now the issue with the above code is by using a negative positioning, then I leave a massive gap at the bottom of the page. However I have also tried:

- Using an absolute positioning on the wrapper div. Works perfect in keeping the page the correct size however then the bottom div floats to the bottom of the viewport
- Using a faux method of making the bottom div look like a full width div by using a background image on body; unfortunately this just sticks it to the bottom of the viewport instead of the bottom of the page due to no content being between both background divs.

Now I have thought about keeping the wrapper occurring naturally between both of the background divs so they do not overlap at all and then put divs inside of those background divs lined up with the wrapper however that becomes a bit of a nightmare that I want to avoid because then I have to struggle to try and align the content that overlaps them as each of those "section divs" would have to be split into two (imagine trying to make a paragraph look like one because it is spread between two divs).

So my question is - am I going about this the wrong way and overlooking something that I could be doing differently to make this work?

Comment: I don't understand the "I cannot get it to behave correctly on the bottom div." By the looks of the snippet, the wrapper is also atop the bottom div, the same as the top div

Comment: Weird that you say that; I opened up Chrome and Edge and they both look like they should. So its just firefox and firefox developer that the issue seems to persist on.